# List of Browsers and their default trusted root certification authorities

Tags: browser, root, certificate, trust

I've been searching around for this for a day and haven't found anything about it. I am trying to determine which browsers have which trusted root certification authorities by default.

I am especially interested in older browsers that have not been updated (like an original version of IE 6 without all the service packs installed).

Does anyone out there have any ideas about this or how to go about finding this info?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Mozilla (2007):
http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/certs/included/

Safari iOS 2:
http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2185